# Disable nginx fastcgi_cache when disk is full

Tags: nginx, cache, fastcgi, disk-space-utilization, disk-cache

When there is no disk space, nginx is still able to work correctly.

It can serve static files, and it can pass the request to a fastcgi server (such as PHP), and it can serve the dynamic response to the client.

The problem happens if `fastcgi_cache` is turned on, and the disk is full. Before serving the response to the client, nginx tries to save it into a file, and that fails (because there is no disk space). Is there a way to configure nginx so it doesn't fail when the disk is full, and `fastcgi_cache` is turned on? The ideal solution would be just not inserting the new record into the cache, when there is not enough space for it. Is such option possible, while keeping `fastcgi_cache` generally turned on?

Comment: Nginx doesn't really allow you to reference available disk space anywhere, so I don't think it's possible to do via normal nginx. There might be a way to do it with the Lua module but then you're moving into a complex solution and may as well just set you proper server monitoring to warn you if the disk space is close to running out.

Comment: You could `max_size` flag of `proxy_cache_path` to limit cache size on disk.